# Is there a loopback-soap-connector example?

Tags: loopbackjs

I would like to use Loopback to do CRUD via SOAP after having expose it as REST with the SOAP connector (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/SOAP+connector).  Can someone provide me code examples of this?  I have not been able to find such docs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's one in the [loopback-example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example) repo:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-connector/tree/soap